# Como Armazenar os dados deste código?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, localstorage, fopen

/*É para pegar os dados que estão aparecendo lá exemplo quando clica no botão aparece o horário e quantidade de cliques quero pegar essas duas informações e armazenar em qualquer lugar que de para armazenar exemplo localstorage ou em arquivo .txt –*/

```
<h2>Cliques</h2>

<button name="tempo" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 
 Date()">
 Clique </button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<button name="clique" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
    Curtir <span class="badge"> 0 </span>
</button>

<script>
 var contador = document.querySelector('.badge');

 document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
 var numero = parseInt(contador.textContent) + 1;
 contador.textContent = numero;
 });
     
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: que dados? só tem uma variável ai, se não explicar bem a dificuldade não há como ajudar

Comment: e para pegar os dados que estão aparecendo lá exemplo quando clica no botão aparece o horário e quantidade de cliques quero pegar essas duas informações e armazenar em qualquer lugar que de para armazenar exemplo localstorage ou em arquivo .txt

Comment: Bem vindo(a) à plataforma. E, desde já, sujiro a leitura dos seguintes artigos: [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas?cb=1). Ambos artigos, vos ensinará como elaborar uma boa pergunta, evitando com isso, votos negativos e, até mesmo, de fechamento. Boa sorte! e volte sempre!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não seria bom pegar os dados do span que está dentro do button, até porque o valor que é para aparecer lá é o que está armazenado, então eu peguei seu html e modifiquei ele para armazenar a quantidade de like e a data do último like (tem como fazer tipo um histórico é só iniciar a let like como um array e da push nela), logo depois eu atualizo os dados assim vai contar os like e mostrar a data html modificado logo abaixo:
*OBS: armazenei os dados no localStorage.*

---

---

HTML:

```
<h2>Likes</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>
<button name="clique" class="btn btn-primary" id="like" type="button">
    Likes <span class="badge" id="likeQt"> 0 </span>
</button>
<p id="date" style="display: none;">Data e horário do último like: <span id="dateLike" ></span></p>
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
// inicializando script depois que a pagina for carregada
    $().ready(function(){
```

Chamando a função de atualizar os dados do span e data quando a pagina for carregada:

```
        // Atualizar span likesQt
        atualizarSpan();
```

Função para criar/atualizar dados no localStorage:

```
        function dadosClick(){
            if(typeof(localStorage)){
                let likes= '';
                if(localStorage.likes){
                    // Pega os dados armazenados caso exista
                    likes=JSON.parse(localStorage.likes);
                    // adicionando 1 mais o número atual de like e atualizando a data
                    likes={numberLike:Number(likes.numberLike)+1,date:Date()};
                    // inserindo dados atualizados
                    localStorage.likes=JSON.stringify(likes);
                    console.table(JSON.parse(localStorage.likes));
                    // Atualizar span likesQt
                    atualizarSpan();
                }else{
                    // criando dados
                    likes={numberLike:1,date:Date()};
                    // adicionando dados
                    localStorage.likes=JSON.stringify(likes);
                    // mostrar dados no console
                    console.table(JSON.parse(localStorage.likes));
                    // Atualizar span likesQt
                    atualizarSpan();
                }

            }else{
                alert('Navegador não suporta localStorage.');
            }
        }
```

Função para atualizar os dados do span que está dentro do button:

```
        // Atualizar span likes
        function atualizarSpan(){
            // verificando se existe dados
            if(localStorage.likes){
            var likeQt=JSON.parse(localStorage.likes);
            // mostrar data
            $("#date").show("slow");
            $("#dateLike").html(likeQt.date);
            // atualizando dados do span likeQt
            $("#likeQt").html(likeQt.numberLike);
            }
        }
```

Quando clicar no button chamar a função de criar/atualizar as informações:

```
        // quando clicar no botão ele vai chamar a função dadosClick para adicionar o like
        $("#like").click(function(){
            dadosClick();
        });

    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado! mas,como poderia fazer para armazenar de 1 em 1 por exemplo está pegando tudo certo lá porém queria que pegasse todos os segundos e os cliques  separadamente não que um gravasse em cima do outro entende?

Comment: é só iniciar a let likes como um array, depois fica dando push na variável assim você teria um historico dos likes.

Comment: tentei fazer mas não consegui poderia me mostrar em código dei push na variavel porém trava no 1 like